# Applescript Adobe Acrobat Pro Save Image To PDF

Tags: applescript, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to compile an applescript to get Adobe Acrobat Pro to save a selected image within a PDF to a JPEG.

This is what I have so far but I am not getting it to work.

Many thanks
Darryl

tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    activate -- bring up acrobat

```
tell application "System Events"

    tell process "Acrobat"
        click menu item "Save As" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Image" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Save As"
        click menu item "JPEG" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Image" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
activate application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Acrobat"
        click menu item "JPEG" of menu 1 of menu item "Image" of menu 1 of menu item "Save As" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        click button "Save" of window "Save As"
    end tell
end tell
```

Tested on OS X 10.9.4 | Adobe Acrobat Pro 10.1.10

Comment: This saves the whole page. If selecting an image in Acrobat and right clicking on it and selecting save image. Please see if you have a work around this.

Answer (score 0):

One issue... My excitement was a little premature...
This saves the whole page. If selecting an image in Acrobat and right clicking on it and selecting save image. Please see if you have a work around this.

Comment: Unfortunately the Adobe Scripting Library doesn't allow gui scripting into the PDF itself (there are no elements there) so you would have to resort to a hybrid system like applescript + mouse tools where you can control the mouse with a coordinate system to perform your clicks.  This only helpful of course if your image will always be in the same coordinate space.